# Share USB Printer from Android Device to Network

Tags: services, printing

Is there any form of printer sharing FROM an Android device (In my case, a generic AMLogic Android Box, 4.2 or 4.4, full sized host USB ports) to a network? Specific method doesn't matter, CUPS, IPP, Jetdirect, would all work, even something like a drop box service where I send a pdf and it automatically prints.

Searching around, I have not seen anything for this direction, everyone wants to print from Android to an existing network printer, but I would like my Android box to be the server. It seems every other kind of server has been implemented, network shares, screencasting/vnc, keyboard and remote control, etc, but not print serving.

If running it as an underlying linux service is required, what is the best method for this? My searching comes up short.